# Coset variety of an algebraic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p\geq0$. An affine algebraic group $G$ is an affine algebraic variety (a Zariski closed subset of $k^m$ for some $m$) such that multiplication and inversion map are morphisms of varieties. An example is the special linear group $SL_n(k)=SL_n$.

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group and let $H\leq G$ be a closed subgroup. In general $\Omega=G/H$ is a variety (quasi-projective a priori, however if they are both reductive $\Omega$ is affine).

Assume $\dim\Omega>0$. Is $\Omega$ (non-) irreducible, in general? What about if we make stronger assumption on $G$ and $H$? For example, what happen if $G=GL_{2n}$ and $H=GL_n\wr S_2$; or $G=GL_n$ and $H=O_n$? In the first case $H$ is the subgroup that fixes a decomposition $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ of $V=k^{2n}$ where $\dim V_1=\dim V_2$; in the second case $H=O_n$ is the orthogonal group, i.e. the stabiliser of a non-degenerate quadratic form defined on $V=k^n$ ($n$ even if $p=2$).

Comment: $\Omega$ is irreducible if $G$ is irreducible because it is the image under the projection morphism of $G$. Since $GL$ is always irreducible, in the cases you've mentioned, $\Omega$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks -- so if $G=O_n$ (in this case $G=SO_n\cup SO_n\tau$) then $\Omega$ may not be irreducible. However it must have at most 2 irreducible components, right?

Comment: Correct. The number of irreducible components of the image is bounded above by the number of irreducible components of the domain. This is totally analogous to the results related to connected components in standard topology. The underlying reason is the same: morphisms in the respective categories preserve connectedness/irreducibility.